# Error in Python Self Test suite after implementing Custom Item Display for Sonos

Tags: sonos

I implemented Custom Item Display for my music service, as per the instruction available in the [Sonos documentation for Customizing Item Display](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/?q=node/420).

When I run the Python Self Test suite, I am getting the following error: 
*Element 'PresentationMap', attribute 'type': [facet 'enumeration'] The value 'DisplayType' is not an element of the set {'NowPlayingRatings', 'ListOverlays', 'InfoView', 'ArtWorkSizeMap', 'BrowseIconSizeMap', 'Search'}.*

Note that I am replacing the Sonos.wsdl file in the test suite with the one from Sonos website ([Sonos.wsdl](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/sites/default/files/Sonos.wsdl)), as this one contains the 'displayType' related changes.

This is how my Presentation Map xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Presentation>
    <PresentationMap type="DisplayType">
        <DisplayType id="genreGrid">
            <DisplayMode>GRID</DisplayMode>
        </DisplayType>
        <DisplayType id="genreList">
            <DisplayMode>LIST</DisplayMode>
        </DisplayType>
        <DisplayType id="genreHero">
            <DisplayMode>HERO</DisplayMode>
        </DisplayType>
        <DisplayType id="genreEditorial">
            <DisplayMode>EDITORIAL</DisplayMode>
        </DisplayType>
        <DisplayType id="playlist">
          <Lines>
            <Line token="title"/>
            <Line token="summary"/>
          </Lines>
        </DisplayType>
    </PresentationMap>

    <--! Other PresetationMap tags (NowPlayingRatings, InfoView, Search, BrowseIconSizeMap)-->
</Presentation>
```

Note also that when I remove the DisplayType tag from the Presentation Map xml file, the error does not  appear anymore, but of course the display would be back to normal without the custom item display that I implemented.

I think the error is showing because the presentationmap.xsd in the test suite does not contain the DisplayType. How can I fix this in order to pass the test and avoid this error while keeping the custom item display that I implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ignore this failure for now. We have an issue opened to get the self-test updated so it no longer throws that error. We will update this thread once the issue is resolved and published.